# HandshakeException: Handshake error in client (OS Error: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER(tls_record.cc:231))

Tags: java, flutter, websocket

HandshakeException: Handshake error in client (OS Error: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER(tls_record.cc:231))

While connecting from flutter app to Spring boot I am getting this error, I want to make web socket communication between flutter app and spring boot application.

HandshakeException: Handshake error in client (OS Error: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER(tls_record.cc:231))

While connecting from flutter app to Spring boot I am getting this error, I want to make web socket communication between flutter app and spring boot application

my use case is like I want to show notification count on bell Icon whenever new notification get added and that count will increase i want to show that count on bell Icon.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.